# In React Router v6, how to check form is dirty before leaving page/route

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, material-ui

Below are the package versions I'm using.

```
React version - 16.13.1
react-router-dom version - 6.0.0-beta.0
react-redux version 7.2.0
Material UI version 4.11.0
```

How/what is the best way to check that a form `isDirty` (has changed) when the user is trying to leave the current page? I would like to prompt "Are you sure want to leave...." if the form `isDirty`.

I will fetch the data from within `useEffect()` and use a redux reducer to render the UI.

Should I declare a variable to keep the original fetched data for dirty checking?

This is what I am doing, but it is not working correctly.

component.js

```
 useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchUserInfo();
 })
```

action.js

```
export function fetchUserInfo() {
 return (dispatch) => {
     dispatch({type: USER_INITIALSTATE, {Name: 'abc', Age: 20}} 
     )
 }
}
```

userReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  processing: false,
  success: false,
  fail: false,
  Profile: {}
}
let oriState;
let State;
const UserReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === USER_INITIALSTATE) {
    oriState = {Profile: action.data};
    State = {...state, Profile: action.data};
    return {...state, Profile: action.data};
  } else if (action.type === OTHERS_ACTION) {
     //update field change
     return {...state, xxx}
  }
}
export const userIsDirty = state => {
  if (oriState && State) {
    return JSON.stringify(oriState.Profile) !== JSON.stringify(State.Profile);
  }
  return false;
};
export default UserReducer;
```

So in my component I call `userIsDirty` to return the isDirty boolean, but I **haven't figured out how** to catch the leave page event and use this as a trigger to do the dirty form checking.

So how to detect leaving the current page? I tried something on useEffect return(component umount), but the props is not getting the updated INITIALSTATE state (meaning I will get Profile: {}), because it only runs once, but if I add the useEffect optional array argument, I get an infinite loop(maybe I set it wrong?).

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchUserInfo();
    return () => {
      console.log(props); //not getting initial state object
    };
  }, []);
```

Am I doing this the correct way? What have I missed? Is there a better/correct solution to achieve what I want?

Thanks @gdh, `useBlocker` is the one I want. I am using it to popup a confirmation dialog.

I will share my complete codesandbox, I believe this may be helpful for someone in the future.

[show confirmation dialog by using useBlocker](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-6-use-prompt-use-blocker-kce6k?file=/example.js:3429-3437)

Comment: If i understand the problem correctly, you are trying to check if the form data is changed by the user and accordingly show a confirmation message when a user tries to exit the page, right?

Comment: @ManuSharma yes, I would like to do something similiar to this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-preventing-transitions-custom-modal-with-hooks-l215t?file=/example.js
but this is using react-router v5... I would like to use v6 method.
based on this document(https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#prompt) I saw there is a hook call useBlocker, but I've no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Update:

**Prompt, usePrompt and useBlocker have been removed from react-router-dom**. This answer will not currently work, though this might change. The github issue, opened Oct 2021, is [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139)

### The answer...

This answer uses router v6.

1. **You can use [usePrompt](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#useprompt).**

- usePrompt will show the confirm modal/popup when you go to another route i.e. on mount.
- A generic alert with message when you try to close the browser. It handles beforeunload internally

```js
usePrompt("Hello from usePrompt -- Are you sure you want to leave?", isBlocking);
```

2. **You can use [useBlocker](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#useblocker)**

- useBlocker will simply block user when attempting to navigating away i.e. on unmount
- A generic alert with message when you try to close the browser. It handles beforeunload internally

```js
useBlocker(
    () => "Hello from useBlocker -- are you sure you want to leave?",
    isBlocking
  );
```

[Demo for both 1 & 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-6-use-prompt-use-blocker-17r2f?file=/example.js:1028-1237)

3. You can also use [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event). But you have to do your own logic. [See an example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pwrux)

Comment: After the release of React-Router v6.0.0-beta.7 and also on current official release v6.0.2 usePrompt and useBlocker has been removed. They will revisit these hooks/similar in the future.

Comment: None of these work in react router v6 anymore

Comment: did you solve that? @rmorse

Comment: Ah yes, they removed those hooks in the beta, but had them in 6.0.0 alpha - it was suggested we add them to our own projects for now (so I made a gist to make it easier) - https://gist.github.com/rmorse/426ffcc579922a82749934826fa9f743

Comment: @rmorse unfortunately it seems UNSAFE_NavigationContext has also been removed from react-router-dom

Comment: Ouch yeah, 5 days ago in a new release... I didn't update/test yet, but I didn't see it deprecated.. if I look at the codebase it seems to be there still: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/search?q=UNSAFE_NavigationContext

Comment: Well, while the developers have created the current version 6 of react-router, the hooks `useBlocker` and `usePrompt` were removed..

Comment: Links obviously do not work anymore.

Comment: Outdated - Update Links please

Answer (score 10):

Just adding an additional answer for React Router v6 users.

As of v6.0.0-beta - useBlocker and usePrompt were removed ([to be added back in at a later date](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139#issuecomment-953816315)).

It was suggsested if we need them in v6.0.2 (current version at the time of writing) that we should use existing code as an example.

[Here is the code directly from the the alpha for these hooks.](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/commit/256cad70d3fd4500b1abcfea66f3ee622fb90874#diff-b60f1a2d4276b2a605c05e19816634111de2e8a4186fe9dd7de8e344b65ed4d3L344-L381)

So to add the hooks back in would be this code (anywhere in your app for usage):
** I only copied the code for react-router-dom - if you're using native, then you'll need to check the above link for the other `usePrompt` hook

```js
/**
 * These hooks re-implement the now removed useBlocker and usePrompt hooks in 'react-router-dom'.
 * Thanks for the idea @piecyk https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139#issuecomment-953816315
 * Source: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/commit/256cad70d3fd4500b1abcfea66f3ee622fb90874#diff-b60f1a2d4276b2a605c05e19816634111de2e8a4186fe9dd7de8e344b65ed4d3L344-L381
 */
import { useContext, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext as NavigationContext } from 'react-router-dom';
/**
 * Blocks all navigation attempts. This is useful for preventing the page from
 * changing until some condition is met, like saving form data.
 *
 * @param  blocker
 * @param  when
 * @see https://reactrouter.com/api/useBlocker
 */
export function useBlocker( blocker, when = true ) {
    const { navigator } = useContext( NavigationContext );

    useEffect( () => {
        if ( ! when ) return;

        const unblock = navigator.block( ( tx ) => {
            const autoUnblockingTx = {
                ...tx,
                retry() {
                    // Automatically unblock the transition so it can play all the way
                    // through before retrying it. TODO: Figure out how to re-enable
                    // this block if the transition is cancelled for some reason.
                    unblock();
                    tx.retry();
                },
            };

            blocker( autoUnblockingTx );
        } );

        return unblock;
    }, [ navigator, blocker, when ] );
}
/**
 * Prompts the user with an Alert before they leave the current screen.
 *
 * @param  message
 * @param  when
 */
export function usePrompt( message, when = true ) {
    const blocker = useCallback(
        ( tx ) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
            if ( window.confirm( message ) ) tx.retry();
        },
        [ message ]
    );

    useBlocker( blocker, when );
}
```

Then the usage would be:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const formIsDirty = true; // Condition to trigger the prompt.
    usePrompt( 'Leave screen?', formIsDirty );
    return (
        <div>Hello world</div> 
    );
};
```

Comment: This works for me, but I'm a bit concerned it must have been removed for a reason. The fact that it disappeared silently and there's still tons of stuff telling you to use it leaves a very weird taste.

Comment: @bbsimonbb I have the same feeling, but it seems people are using it with success. I am going to add it to my project with a note to keep checking for a properly supported usePrompt/useBlocker in v6

Comment: I think this implementation matches the previous implementation (pre v6), but I have found some issues with both versions...  my assumption is, instead of re-releasing the same features in the same way, they want to revisit and do a rewrite ground up to tackle the issues they have faced in previous versions...

Comment: Not sure how this can work, if its once blocked, and then WHEN changes to false and the useEffect returns false, then the unblock handler will not be removed from history api, meaning the navigation will be still block event if when is false

Comment: Not 100% on that, this is just what they had in the codebase at the time of writing.  I believe now, the approach above may no longer be neeed as they've re-implemented useBlocker as unstable_useBlocker and unstable_usePrompt - https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139#issuecomment-1396078490

Answer (score 2):

@Devb your question and update were super helpful and saved me a lot of time. Thank you! created a HOC based on your code. might be useful to someone.
props on Wrapped Component:

- setPreventNavigation - sets when to block navigation
- provideLeaveHandler - sets the function that will run when you try to change a route and you are blocked for navigation
- confirmNavigation - continue navigation
- cancelNavigation - stop Navigation

  ```
   import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react'
   import { useNavigate, useBlocker, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

   export default function withPreventNavigation(WrappedComponent) {
     return function preventNavigation(props) {
       const navigate = useNavigate()
       const location = useLocation()
       const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState(null)
       const [confirmedNavigation, setConfirmedNavigation] = useState(false)
       const [shouldBlock, setShouldBlock] = useState(false)

      let handleLeave = null

       const cancelNavigation = useCallback(() => {
         setshouldBlock(false)
       },[])

       const handleBlockedNavigation = useCallback(
         nextLocation => {
           if (
             !confirmedNavigation &&
             nextLocation.location.pathname !== location.pathname
           ) {
             handleLeave(nextLocation)
             setLastLocation(nextLocation)
             return false
           }
           return true
         },
         [confirmedNavigation]
       )

       const confirmNavigation = useCallback(() => {
         setConfirmedNavigation(true)
       }, [])

       useEffect(() => {
         if (confirmedNavigation && lastLocation) {
           navigate(lastLocation.location.pathname)
         }
       }, [confirmedNavigation, lastLocation])

       const provideLeaveHandler = handler => {
         handleLeave = handler
       }

       useBlocker(handleBlockedNavigation, shouldBlock)

       return (
         <WrappedComponent
           {...props}
           provideLeaveHandler={provideLeaveHandler}
           setPreventNavigation={setShouldBlock}
           confirmNavigation={confirmNavigation}
           cancelNavigation={cancelNavigation} />
       )
     }
   }
  ```

Comment: Just a heads up that the boolean return values you have within the `handleBlockedNavigation` callback have no effect - I originally had this in my answer as well based on @Devb's codesandbox, but after looking at the typescript spec realized that any return values are ignored, so likely best to remove them to avoid any interpretation that they are having an intentional effect.  If you actually want to conditionally cancel the blocking, you'll want to use `nextLocation.retry()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

#### Posting this for someone who wants custom UI `pop-up/modal box` instead for browser's `default prompt` and they are using `react-router (v4)` with `history`.

You can make use of `custom history` and configure your `router` like

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
export const history = createBrowserHistory()

... 
import { history } from 'path/to/history';

<Router history={history}>
  <App/>
</Router>
```

and then in your **custom prompt component** you can make use of `history.block` like

```
import { history } from 'path/to/history';

class MyCustomPrompt extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      this.unblock = history.block(targetLocation => {
           // take your action here     
           return false;
      });
   }
   componentWillUnmount() {
      this.unblock();
   }
   render() {
      //component render here
   }
}
```

Add this `MyCustomPrompt` in your components where ever you want to block navigation.

Answer (score 1):

As explained at https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139, `useBlocker` and `usePrompt` are now available in React Router v6 (as of v6.7); however, as of v6.9.0, there are a few caveats:

- You have to use one of the new data routers (`RouterProvider`), not the older `BrowserRouter`, etc.
- They're still flagged as `unstable_`.
- They aren't yet documented.

See https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/examples/navigation-blocking/src/app.tsx for sample usage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event).

Read carefully as not all browsers are compliant with `event.preventDefault()`.

In the event handler you can do the checks you want and call prevent the window to close depending on your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The hooks [@gdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13207394/gdh) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62845324/5202550) were removed by the developers team of react-router. Because of that you can't use `usePrompt` or `useBlocker` with the current version of react-router (v6).

But the team mentioned they are heavily working on the features. [reference](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md#prompt-is-not-currently-supported)

If somebody wants to implement the changes the remix team made to offer the functionalities of the hooks you can take a look at this answer from github. [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139#issuecomment-977790637)

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out a solution which can show custom dialog, block navigation and resume asynchronous.

You can find a discussion about this on github.
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139

With everyone's help, I made the final solution.

```js
import { useState, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext as NavigationContext } from 'react-router-dom';
import type { History } from 'history';


/** @description Blocks all navigation attempts.
 *  @param when {boolean}  Whether to start intercepting navigation.
 *  @example
 *  const [flag, setFlag, next] = usePrompt(false);
 *  useEffect(() => {
 *     if (flag) {
 *  //     do something like show a dialog etc;
 *  //     at the right time resume bocked navigate
 *         next();
 *     }
 *   }, [flag]);

 */
export const usePrompt = (when = false) => {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  const confirm = useRef<any>(null);
  const context = useRef<any>(null);
  const { navigator } = useContext(NavigationContext);
  const blockNavigator = navigator as History;

  const next = useCallback(() => {
    confirm.current();
    context.current?.retry?.();
  }, [flag]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!when) return;
    const unblock = blockNavigator.block((tx) => {
      setFlag(true);
      context.current = tx;
    });
    confirm.current = unblock;
    return unblock;
  }, [blockNavigator, when]);

  return [flag, setFlag, next] as const;
};
```

Comment: I get an error "confirm.current is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in other comments `usePrompt` and `useBlocker` have been removed from React router. However you can use their "unstable" counterparts:

`unstable_usePrompt` and `unstable_useBlocker`.

I used it as:

```js
  unstable_usePrompt({
    when: isDirty,
    message: leaveConfirmationText
  })
```

There is the warning about usage of these hooks:

> Warning: This has *a lot of rough edges* and behaves very differently (and
> very incorrectly in some cases) across browsers if user click addition
> back/forward navigations while the confirm is open.  Use at your own risk.

After a brief test it worked for me and I haven't noticed any issues. I can afford a certain level of instability in my case so it's okay for my case. I'll update the answer if I found anything specifically weird about these versions.

Answer (score 0):

The hooks mentioned in accepted answer were removed in latest version of react-router. You can't use `usePrompt` or `useBlocker` anymore with the current version of react-router (v6).

You can use this simple hook to block navigation based on certain state changes or criteria.

#### Usage

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import useNavigationPrompt from 'use-navigation-prompt';
    
function App() {
    const [isNavigationBlocked, setIsNavigationBlocked] = useState(false);
    useNavigationPrompt(isNavigationBlocked);
    
    return (
        <div>
            Navigation is: { !isNavigationBlocked ? "not" : "" } Blocked
            <button 
                onClick={() => setIsNavigationBlocked(prevIsNavigationBlocked => !prevIsNavigationBlocked)}
            >
                Toggle
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
    
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with `BrowserHistory` and `unstable_HistoryRouter` (safe) from `react-router-dom` v6.**

You can define a custom hook named `useUnsavedChanges`. This hook is used to block navigation away from the page when there are unsaved changes (`isDirty` is `true`). It takes two parameters: `isDirty`, which indicates whether there are unsaved changes, and `save`, which is the function responsible for saving data.

Inside the `useEffect`, it creates a `history.block` that listens for navigation events. When `isDirty` is `true`, it opens a modal dialog to confirm if the user wants to continue with navigation or save changes. If the user chooses to save, it calls the save function, and if successful, it continues with navigation.

**yourHistory.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**yourApp.jsx**

```
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './yourHistory';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('yourApp'));
root.render(
  <HistoryRouter history={history}>
    <YourRoutes />
  </HistoryRouter>
);
```

**YourPage.jsx**

```
const YourPage = () => {
  // tracks whether there are unsaved changes in a form
  const [isDirty, setIsDirty] = useState(false);

  // custom hook
  const useUnsavedChanges(isDirty, save);

  // saving data
  const save = async () => {
    try {
      // Perform some action (e.g., saving data)
    } catch(error) {
      // Handle any errors that occur during the action
    }
  }

  return (
    <YourForm onSubmit={save}>
      <YourInput onChange={() => setIsDirty(true)}/>
      <YourButton type="submit">Save<YourButton/>
    </YourForm>
  ) 
}
```

**useUnsavedChanges.jsx**

```
import history from './yourHistory';

const useUnsavedChanges = (isDirty, save) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let unblock;
    if(isDirty) {
      unblock = history.block((tx) => {
        const continueNavigation = () => {
          unblock();
          tx.retry();
        };
        const saveAndContinue = async () => {
          try {
            await save();
            continueNavigation();
          } catch(error) {
            // Handle any errors that occur during the action
          }
        }
        // first param: click on "leave without saving"
        // second param: click on "save and leave"
        openYourModal(continueNavigation, saveAndContinue);
      });
    }
    return () => {
      if(typeof unblock === 'function') unblock();
    };
  }, [isDirty])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since React Router v6.7.0, [`unstable_usePrompt`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.19.0/hooks/use-prompt) is available for use, which prompts the user with `window.confirm` before navigating away. Note that it requires a data router (e.g. one created with the most recommended [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.19.0/routers/create-browser-router)).

Call the hook directly inside your component, e.g.

```js
import { unstable_usePrompt } from 'react-router-dom';
function MyComp() {
    unstable_usePrompt({
        message: 'Are you sure you want to leave?',
        when: ({ currentLocation, nextLocation }) => {
            // return true or false to indicate whether the user should be prompted first
        }
    });
}
```

However, [`useBlocker`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.19.0/hooks/use-blocker) is recommended instead for providing consistency across browsers as it enables handling how the confirmation message is styled. (It also requires a data router.) As of React Router v6.19.0, it no longer has the unstable prefix whereas there are no plans to remove the unstable prefix from `unstable_usePrompt` due to its non-deterministic behavior in different browsers.

Here is an edited version of the `useBlocker` example from the documentation:

```js
import { useBlocker, Form } from "react-router-dom";
function ImportantForm() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  // Block navigating elsewhere when data has been entered into the input
  const blocker = useBlocker(({ currentLocation, nextLocation }) =>
      value !== "" && currentLocation.pathname !== nextLocation.pathname);
  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <label>
        Enter some important data:
        <input
          name="data"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>

      {blocker.state === "blocked" && (
        <div>
          <p>Are you sure you want to leave?</p>
          <button onClick={() => blocker.proceed()}>
            Proceed
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => blocker.reset()}>
            Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**: `Prompt`, `usePrompt` and `useBlocker` used in this answer **have since been removed from react-router-dom**. **This answer will not currently work**, though this might change. The github issue requesting these hooks to be added back, opened Oct 2021, is [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139)

I was facing the same situation of attempting to utilize a customized "pleasant" UI confirmation dialog integrating with react router v6 beta's `useBlocker` hook for blocking route transitions when the current route's form has unsaved modifications.  I started with the code from the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-6-use-prompt-use-blocker-kce6k?file=/example.js:3429-3437) linked in the `UPDATED` section at the bottom of this question.  I found this custom hook implementation to not work for all of my needs, so I adapted it to support an optional regular expression parameter to define a set of routes that should not be blocked.  Also of note, the codesandbox implementation returns a boolean from the callback passed into `useBlocker`, but I found this has no effect or usefulness, so I removed this.  Here is my full TypeScript implementation of a revised custom hook:

useNavigationWarning.ts

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useBlocker, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Blocker } from 'history';

export function useNavigationWarning(
  when: boolean,
  exceptPathsMatching?: RegExp
) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState<any>(null);
  const [confirmedNavigation, setConfirmedNavigation] = useState<boolean>(
    false
  );

  const cancelNavigation = useCallback(() => {
    setShowPrompt(false);
  }, []);

  const handleBlockedNavigation = useCallback<Blocker>(
    nextLocation => {
      const shouldIgnorePathChange = exceptPathsMatching?.test(
        nextLocation.location.pathname
      );
      if (
        !(confirmedNavigation || shouldIgnorePathChange) &&
        nextLocation.location.pathname !== location.pathname
      ) {
        setShowPrompt(true);
        setLastLocation(nextLocation);
      } else if (shouldIgnorePathChange) {
        // to cancel blocking based on the route we need to retry the nextLocation
        nextLocation.retry();
      }
    },
    [confirmedNavigation, location.pathname, exceptPathsMatching]
  );

  const confirmNavigation = useCallback(() => {
    setShowPrompt(false);
    setConfirmedNavigation(true);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (confirmedNavigation && lastLocation?.location) {
      navigate(lastLocation.location.pathname);
      // Reset hook state
      setConfirmedNavigation(false);
      setLastLocation(null);
    }
  }, [confirmedNavigation, lastLocation, navigate]);

  useBlocker(handleBlockedNavigation, when);

  return [showPrompt, confirmNavigation, cancelNavigation] as const;
}
```