# Detecting user leaving page with react-router-dom v6.0.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to show Dialog Box for unsaved changes before navigating to other route or page in ReactJS web app. I tried different solution from Stackoverflow but didn't succeeded. Most of solution related to older version. I need for version **6.0.2** (react-router-dom). Anyone who can help me out in this really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In React Router v6, how to check form is dirty before leaving page/route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792342/in-react-router-v6-how-to-check-form-is-dirty-before-leaving-page-route)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**How to resolve my problem?**
Instead of downgrading, I created two custom hooks.

1. `useCallbackPrompt` Hook
2. `useBlocker` Hook

**`useCallbackPrompt` Hook**
This hook handles a popup to show & hide and update location on the base of specific conditions.
How it looks like.
[image: useCallbackPrompt Hook]

**useBlocker Hook**
This hooks blocks users from navigating away if there are any changes
[image: useBlocker Hook]

**How I am using useCallbackPrompt in my component**
[image: component where I am using useCallbackPrompt hook]

I created state `showDialog`; If the user changes something on the current page/form it will update the state `showDialog` and If the user tries to navigate away the prompt will be shown, and ask if the user wants to stay or not.

Here is the [Live Demo Link](https://detect-user-leaving-page-react-router-dom-v6.netlify.app/home)

Here is the [GITHUB REPO LINK](https://github.com/Bilal-Bangash/detecting-route-change-react-route-dom-v6)

Link for [Post](https://dev.to/bangash1996/detecting-user-leaving-page-with-react-router-dom-v602-33ni)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `usePrompt` or `useBlocker` to detect and show a prompt before leaving to another route if they have any unsaved changes (for example in a unsaved form element).

However, in the [official](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) documentation of react router v6 the following is mentioned:

> from v5 (along with usePrompt and useBlocker from the v6
> betas) are not included in the current released version of v6.

I checked on Github as well, even the current version 6.2.1 doesn't support `usePrompt` and `useBlocker`.

---

**But you can still downgrade to v5 or 6.0.0-alpha.5
the following code is working with the react router v6.0.0-alpha.5**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useHistory,
  usePrompt,
  useBlocker,
  Routes
} from "react-router-dom";

// Sometimes you want to prevent the user from
// navigating away from a page. The most common
// use case is when they have entered some data
// into a form but haven't submitted it yet, and
// you don't want them to lose it.

export default function PreventingTransitionsExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Form</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/one">One</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/two">Two</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact children={<BlockingForm />} />
        <Route path="/one" children={<h3>One</h3>} />
        <Route path="/two" children={<h3>Two</h3>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

function BlockingForm() {
  let [isBlocking, setIsBlocking] = useState(false);

  usePrompt(
    "Hello from usePrompt -- Are you sure you want to leave?",
    isBlocking
  );
  // useBlocker(
  //   () => "Hello from useBlocker -- are you sure you want to leave?",
  //   isBlocking
  // );

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.reset();
        setIsBlocking(false);
      }}
    >
      <p>
        Blocking? {isBlocking ? "Yes, click a link or the back button" : "Nope"}
      </p>

      <p>
        <input
          size="50"
          placeholder="type something to block transitions"
          onChange={event => {
            setIsBlocking(event.target.value.length > 0);
          }}
        />
      </p>

      <p>
        <button>Submit to stop blocking</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  );
}
```