# React router v6 doesn't support <Prompt /> or usePrompt

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Migrating a codebase to react-router v6 specifically `v6.2.1` and running into some issues when trying to use `<Prompt />` component or `usePrompt`, turns out they are not available in this version of react-router. Or am I wrong? If anyone have run in to the same issue or if you know a way around this issue, your help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not currently included, though I believe there are plans to reintroduce them later.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792342/in-react-router-v6-how-to-check-form-is-dirty-before-leaving-page-route

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Prompt is currently not supported in v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#prompt-is-not-currently-supported)

You will have to create your own component that performs the check and displays the prompt.

Comment: yup seems like there is no way around it for now, except implementing our own logic

Comment: yeah, still not included in v6.4.3

Comment: Prompt implementation using useBlocker: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75920683/2767413

Answer (score 5):

**As it says in the documentation:**

`<Prompt>` from v5 (along with usePrompt and useBlocker from the v6 betas) are not included in the current released version of v6. We decided we'd rather ship with what we have than take even more time to nail down a feature that isn't fully baked. We will absolutely be working on adding this back in to v6 at some point in the near future, but not for our first stable release of 6.x.

So you have two options:

1. Create your own component and handle the logic there.
2. Downgrade `react-router-dom` to v5.

Source: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#prompt-is-not-currently-supported

Answer (score 0):

**React router v6 doesn't support  or usePrompt.**

You can use this simple hook to block navigation based on certain state changes or criteria.

#### Usage

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import useNavigationPrompt from 'use-navigation-prompt';
    
function App() {
    const [isNavigationBlocked, setIsNavigationBlocked] = useState(false);
    useNavigationPrompt(isNavigationBlocked);
    
    return (
        <div>
            Navigation is: { !isNavigationBlocked ? "not" : "" } Blocked
            <button 
                onClick={() => setIsNavigationBlocked(prevIsNavigationBlocked => !prevIsNavigationBlocked)}
            >
                Toggle
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
    
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beta supported `unstable_usePrompt`:

```
import { unstable_usePrompt } from 'react-router-dom';

unstable_usePrompt({
  message: "Are you sure you want to leave?",
  when: true
})
```

And [here](https://gist.github.com/chaance/2f3c14ec2351a175024f62fd6ba64aa6) is a full example of `<Prompt />` in react router v6 using `unstable_useBlocker` that has all the features

Answer (score 0):

Since React Router v6.7.0, the [`unstable_usePrompt`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.19.0/hooks/use-prompt) hook may be used. Note that this requires a data router (e.g. with [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.19.0/routers/create-browser-router)).

For example:

```js
import { unstable_usePrompt } from 'react-router-dom';
function MyComp() {
    unstable_usePrompt({
        message: 'Are you sure you want to leave?',
        when: ({ currentLocation, nextLocation }) => {
            // return true or false to indicate whether the user should be prompted first
        } // can also just pass a boolean instead of a function here
    });
}
```

However, [`useBlocker`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.19.0/hooks/use-blocker) is recommended instead for providing consistency across browsers as it enables handling how the confirmation message is styled. (It also requires a data router.) As of React Router v6.19.0, it no longer has the unstable prefix whereas there are no plans to remove the unstable prefix from `unstable_usePrompt` due to its non-deterministic behavior in different browsers.

Here is an edited version of the `useBlocker` example from the documentation:

```js
import { useBlocker, Form } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from 'react';
function ImportantForm() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  // Block navigating elsewhere when data has been entered into the input
  const blocker = useBlocker(({ currentLocation, nextLocation }) =>
      value !== "" && currentLocation.pathname !== nextLocation.pathname);
  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <label>
        Enter some important data:
        <input
          name="data"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>

      {blocker.state === "blocked" && (
        <div>
          <p>Are you sure you want to leave?</p>
          <button onClick={() => blocker.proceed()}>
            Proceed
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => blocker.reset()}>
            Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -5):

**Prompt is currently not supported in `react-router-dom` 6**

[Prompt not supported at the moment](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#prompt-is-not-currently-supported)

Resort to the following:

1. Writing your own prompt component
2. installing `react-router-dom 5` and using prompt.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer does not add anything to the previous one. Just vote up for the previous one.

Comment: Yes, I had not seen the ones above until now. Thanks.